# Parallel process in chunks giving no performance benefits

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I have a very huge list ( *huge_list* ) . A function (*inner_fun*) is called for each value of the list. Inner_fun takes around .5 seconds.output of inner_fun is a simple numeric vector of size 3. I am trying to parallelise this approach. After going through many articles , it was mentioned that it is better to divide in chunks when the parallel function is very quick. So i divided it based on cores. But there is no time benefit. I am not able to understand the concept here . Can anyone give few insights on this.  My major concern is that if i am doing something wrong with the code. I am not posting exact codes here. but i have tried to replicate as much as possible

**few observations :**

1. dummy_fun and dummy_fun2 takes around 10 hrs with parallel kept as
   11
2. with no parallel , this goes around 20 hrs.
3. with parallel=2 ,it completes in 15 hrs
4. I am using 12 cores , 60 GB RAM , ubuntu machine

**Code to make cluster**

```
no_of_clusters<-detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(no_of_clusters) ; registerDoParallel(cl) ; 
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("arg1","arg2","inner_fun"))
```

**Function without chunks**

```
dummy_fun<-function(arg1,arg2,huge_list){
  g <- foreach (i = 1: length(huge_list),.combine=rbind,
                .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
                    inner_fun(i,arg1,arg2,huge_list[i])
                }
    return(g)
}
```

**Functions with chunks **

```
dummy_fun2<-function(arg1,arg2,huge_list){
  il<-1:length(huge_list)
  il2<-split(il, ceiling(seq_along(il)/(length(il)/(detectCores()-1))))
  g <- foreach ( i= il2 , .combine=rbind,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  ab1<-lapply(i,function(li) 
           { 
            inner_fun(i,arg1,arg2,huge_list(i))
           }
          )
   do.call(rbind,ab1)
}
   return(g)
}
```

Comment: you should try `profvis` on your (serial) function to check what part you need to improve

Comment: I don't understand why you consider 15 hrs instead of 20 as "no time benefit". You should expect K times better performance (in terms of waiting times) for K cores only for perfectly parallelizable problems, which is a very narrow range of real world problems.

Comment: Could you provide something that is similar to `huge_list` and `inner_fun`? What is the size of `huge_list` (in memory)? Can `inner_fun` be vectorized?

Comment: Sorry for not bringing clarity to my problem statement. we have optimised every possible options within the inner_fun. As mentioned , my intent is to get an understanding on why chunks are not performing better. Assuming the list has around 10000 objects. if if 1 object takes n seconds. if i subdivide the task by computing 1000 objects in a for loop * 10(times parallel) . the time should be much lesser than the current benchmark

Answer (score 4):

You got the chunks wrong. It's not about dividing the indices in chunks of length `no_of_clusters` but rather to divide them in `no_of_clusters` chunks.

Try this out:

```
dummy_fun2 <- function(arg1, arg2, huge_list, inner_fun, ncores) {

  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl), add = TRUE)

  L <- length(huge_list)
  inds <- split(seq_len(L), sort(rep_len(seq_len(NCORES), L)))

  foreach(l = seq_along(inds), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    ab1 <- lapply(inds[[l]], function(i) {
      inner_fun(i, arg1, arg2, huge_list[i])
    })
    do.call(rbind, ab1)
  }
}
```

Further remarks:

1. it's often useless to use more than half of the cores you have on your computer.
2. the option `.multicombine` is automatically used with `rbind`. But the `.maxcombine` is really important (need more than 100). Here, we use `lapply` for the sequential part so this remark doesn't matter.
3. it's useless to have many exports when using `foreach`, it already  exports what is necessary from the environment of `dummy_fun2`.
4. are you sure you want to use `huge_list[i]` (get a list of one element) rather than `huge_list[[i]]` (get the i-th element of the list)?

Comment: Nice answer but I'm curious why you say `it's often useless to use more than half of the cores`? This seems too general a statement to make in my opinion

Comment: Thanks a lot F. Privé . The original code has the chunksize as mentioned by you. while writing it down here , i got it wrong. Anyway i edited it , thanks for noting it. Apart from the chunks , remaining comments have not been tried . I will update soon in a day or two with new results.

Comment: @ChiPak My experience on several applications and configurations. If you have a counter-example, I'd like to know :-)

Comment: @FPrive I think it's true if you have iterations/workers that do not take a *super* long time, but if each iteration takes a *super* long time, `foreach` will use as many cores as available, in my experience.

Comment: Give me an example and I'll be convinced! :')